# Why does my c program not print my error message after a condition is true in my if statement?

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements, printf, conditional-operator

In my program, I want to check if the values input by the user will produce a valid table, if not I want to print an error message.

I used an `if` statement followed by `printf`. This works for all the conditions in my `if` statement except for the `(upper <= 0)` and `(upper <= kmlower)` conditions. When these conditions are true the loop will break but the error message is not printed.

This is my code:

```
/* Description: Program to calculate the flight time of an aeroplane,
 *              and tabulate it for a range of values of the distance
 *              travelled.
 *
 *==================================================================*/

/*==================================================================
 * Systems header files
 *==================================================================*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

/*==================================================================
 * Constant definitions
 *==================================================================*/
#define KMTOMILES 0.621371;
#define  AVGVELOCITY 529;

/*==================================================================
 * Function definitions
 *==================================================================*/

int main(void)
{
    /* Declaration of variables */
    int FlighttHours, intFlighttMin;
    float kmlower, upper, step /*km = lower */;
    float FlighttRem, miles, totalFlightt, floatFlighttMin;

    /* Interact with the user */
    printf("Enter the lower limit on distance in km:\t  ");
    scanf("%f", &kmlower);

    printf("Enter the upper limit on distance in km:\t  ");
    scanf("%f", &upper);

    printf("Enter the step size in km:\t\t\t  ");
    scanf("%f", &step);


    while (kmlower <= upper) /* Create output table */
    {
       ** **/* Check if the values input by the user will produce a valid table */
        if ((kmlower <= 0) || (upper <= 0) || (step <= 0) || (upper <= kmlower))
        {
            printf("\nERROR: these values will not  produce a valid output table\n");
            break;****
        }

        /* Continue loop if no errors */
        else
        {
            /* Print table headers once */
            printf("\n=================================================\n");
            printf("| distance (km) |     hours     |     minutes   |\n");
            printf("|===============================================|\n");

            /* Loop until upper limit is reached */
            while (kmlower <= upper)
            {
                /* Print range of distances */
                printf("|%10.2f\t|", kmlower);

                /* Calculate journey times */
                miles = kmlower * KMTOMILES;
                totalFlightt = miles / AVGVELOCITY;
                FlighttHours = (int)(totalFlightt);
                FlighttRem = totalFlightt - FlighttHours;
                floatFlighttMin = FlighttRem * 60;
                intFlighttMin = round(floatFlighttMin);

                /* Print results */
                printf("\t%d\t|\t%d\t|\n", FlighttHours, intFlighttMin );
                kmlower += step;
            }
        }
    }

    return (0);
}
```

When I run the code and the user input for `kmlower <= 0` or `step <= 0`, my error message is printed.

result when `kmlower <= 0`, with error message:

```
Enter the lower limit on distance in km:         0
Enter the upper limit on distance in km:         4000
Enter the step size in km:                       500

ERROR: these values will not produce a valid output table

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time: 3.977 s
Press any key to continue.
```

result when `step <= 0`, with error message:

```
Enter the lower limit on distance in km:         500
Enter the upper limit on distance in km:         4000
Enter the step size in km:                       0

ERROR: these values will not produce a valid output table

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time: 7.016 s
Press any key to continue.
```

But when the user input for `upper <= 0` or `upper <= kmlower`, the code stops like I want but the error message isn't printed.

result when `upper <= 0`, no error message:

```
Enter the lower limit on distance in km:         500
Enter the upper limit on distance in km:         0
Enter the step size in km:                       200

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time: 14.927 s
Press any key to continue.
```

result when `upper <= kmlower`, no error message:

```
Enter the lower limit on distance in km:         500
Enter the upper limit on distance in km:         400
Enter the step size in km:                       200

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time: 7.084 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Copy-paste *all* text as text into your questions.

Comment: As for your problem, please use a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the code line by line, while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: On a different note, unless you have very specific requirements, please don't use `float` for your floating point values and variables. Use `double` instead.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: snapshots of execution examples are IMHO not as much of a problem as pictures of code.  I did not add the pictures, I merely made the images visible in place of links to pictures.

Comment: @chqrlie Sorry.  Yet be careful about [Do you mess with it?](https://www.flickr.com/photos/31686274@N08/3044388825) 

Comment: OT: Change the 3 prompts to `printf( "%-45s", "Enter the ...." );` and get rid of the variable number of TABs used in each line. They're a maintenance headache. (Could even use `char *fmt = "%-45s"; printf( fmt, "blah blah" );` so the common width is in one location.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problems:

- Key: loop condition while `(kmlower <= upper)` is preventing entry. [@B. Pantalone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77203983/2410359)
- Failed to compile with many warnings enabled.  Save time and enable many, if not all warnings.
- Avoid mixing `float` and `double` math.  In this case, use `double` variables instead of `float`.  [@Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77203939/why-does-my-c-program-not-print-my-error-message-after-a-condition-is-true-in-my?noredirect=1#comment136104111_77203939)
- Poor time calculation:

When `totalFlightt = 123.996`, code will output "123:60" instead of "124:00".

```
| distance (km) |     hours     |     minutes   |
|===============================================|
|      0.00     |     123       |   60          |
```

Alternative code that rounds the entire time to the closest minute and then breaks it into hours/minutes.

```
long totalFlightt_minutes = lround(60.0 * miles / AVGVELOCITY);
printf("\t%ld\t|\t%02ld\t|\n", 
   totalFlightt_minutes / 60, totalFlightt_minutes % 60);
```

---

**Only for the pedantic**

- Conversion constants

OP's `#define KMTOMILES 0.621371` is 5 `float`s away from the best `float` of `0.621371210f`.

Rather than coarse constants, use at least the precision of the type: 9 for `float`, 17 for `double`.

Even better, since KM to mph is an exact fraction, let the compiler figure it out

```
#define KMTOMILES_ALT (10000000.0f/(5280L*12*254))
```

- Right units?

Aviation rarely use [miles_per_hour](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/26389/26231), but [knots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knot_(unit)).

Consider:

```
#define KMTOKNOTS (1000.0/1852)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your loop condition `while (kmlower <= upper)` is preventing entry into the loop when those inputs are used. If you want to see the error message, get rid of the outer loop.

Answer (score 2):

The validity test on the input values is performed inside the body of a `while (kmlower <= upper)` loop.  This initial test is false for the last 2 cases, which explains why you get no output.  Note that this `while` loop is useless and should be removed.

Note also that the definitions of `KMTOMILES` and `AVGVELOCITY` are incorrect: you should remove the trailing `;` in the macro definition, that will prevent use in most expressions unless the macro appears at the end and the trailing `;` just creates an extra empty statement.  Use this instead:

```
#define KMTOMILES 0.621371
#define AVGVELOCITY 529
```